# HTTP client post with optional splat argument not compiled

Tags: crystal-lang

I would like to send HTTP post request by using

```
HTTP::Client#post(path, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, *, form : Hash(String, String) | NamedTuple)
```

I try to do this

```
url = "https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/start"
headers = HTTP::Headers{"X-Authy-API-Key" => api_key}

form = {
  via:          "sms",
  country_code: country_code,
  phone_number: phone_number,
  code_length:  6,
  locale:       "ru",
}.to_h

response = HTTP::Client.post(url, headers: headers, form: form)
```

Unfortunately, I got compilation error

```
no argument named 'form'
Matches are:
 - HTTP::Client#post(path, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, body : BodyType = nil) (trying this one)
 - HTTP::Client#post(path, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, body : BodyType = nil, &block)
 - HTTP::Client#post(path, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, *, form : String | IO)
 - HTTP::Client#post(path, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, *, form : String | IO, &block)
 - HTTP::Client#post(path, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, *, form : Hash(String, String) | NamedTuple)
 - HTTP::Client#post(path, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, *, form : Hash(String, String) | NamedTuple, &block)
```

What is correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This compilation error happens because `.to_h` returns a `Hash(Symbol, Int32 | String)` on your [named tuple](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/named_tuple.html), and that is incompatible with any of the definitions for `HTTP::Client.post`.

To solve this, I suggest to explicitly define `form` as a `Hash(String, String)` and replace the keys and values by their string representation:

```
form : Hash(String, String) = {
  "via"          => "sms",
  "country_code" => country_code.to_s, # assuming this is not a string
  "phone_number" => phone_number,
  "code_length"  => "6",
  "locale"       => "ru",
}
```

Comment: Can I use NamedTuple instead of Hash(String, String)? Look like it allowed `form : Hash(String, String) | NamedTuple`.

Comment: @msa7 Not with the class method `.post` (i.e. `self.post`), but only with the instance method `#post`.  For that you would have to create an instance of `HTTP::Client` first and then call `client.post(path, headers: headers, form: form).  The values of the `NamedTuple` need to be strings as well, otherwise compilation fails again (this time with `no overload matches 'HTTP::Params.encode_www_form_component' with types (Int32 | String), IO+`)

Comment: Alternatively: `form = Hash(String, String){ # ... }`